# cucumber testing scenario fails while using before filter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, cucumber, capybara

I have referred to the link http://railscasts.com/episodes/155-beginning-with-cucumber for testing.

When I use `before_filter :authenticate_user!` in my controller my all cases are failing and when i commented the `before_filter` my all test cases are passing. I am getting following error.

```
Scenario: Create Valid Article   
          Given I have no articles                                
          And I am on the list of articles                       
          When I follow "New Article"                             

 Unable to find link "New Article" (Capybara::ElementNotFound)
  ./features/step_definitions/article_steps.rb:25:in `/^I follow "([^\"]*)"$/'
  features/manage_articles.feature:15:in `When I follow "New Article"'

  And I fill in "article[title]" with "Spuds"        
  And I fill in "Content" with "Delicious potato wedges!" 
  And I press "Create"                                   
  Then I should see "New article created."                
  And I should see "Spuds"                                
  And I should see "Delicious potato wedges!"             
  And I should have 1 article                             

 Failing Scenarios:
   cucumber features/manage_articles.feature:12 # Scenario: Create Valid Article

2 scenarios (1 failed, 1 passed)
14 steps (1 failed, 7 skipped, 6 passed)
```

## article_steps.rb

```
Given /^I have articles titled (.+)$/ do |titles|
  titles.split(', ').each do |title|
   Article.create!(:title => title)
  end
end

When /^I go to the list of articles$/ do
 visit articles_path
end

Then /^I should see "(.*?)"$/ do |arg1|

end

Given /^I have no articles$/ do
 Article.delete_all
end

Given /^I am on the list of articles$/ do
  visit articles_path
end

When /^I follow "([^\"]*)"$/ do |link|
  click_link(link)
end

When /^I fill in "([^\"]*)" with "([^\"]*)"$/ do |field, value|
  fill_in(field, :with => value)
end

When /^I press "([^\"]*)"$/ do |button|
  click_button(button)
end

Then /^I should have ([0-9]+) articles?$/ do |count|
  Article.count.should == count.to_i
end
```

Comment: can you please post your step definations of `/features/step_definitions/article_steps.rb`?

Comment: is there any link on the list of articles page which name is `"New Article"`

Comment: add gem `launchy` to Gemfile and use `save_and_open_page` to see actual page

Comment: @gotva I've used launchy but I don't know how use save_and_open_page as I am new to cucumber..

Comment: Just place `save_and_open_page` in correct place. In your case it is before `click_link` in step `When /^I follow...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on error, capybara can't find the link on page. So as per @gotva, please check that there is link of "New Aritcle" on page or not.

As you have put `before_filter :authenticate_user!` it means that you need used logged in before trying to access the page. But there is no login scenario in the feature.

So I suggest you to add login scenario in the page as per @Rajarshi Das has suggested. If your login scenario is always gonna be included in every feature then you can put that in [Background](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background).

```
Feature: Managing Articles

Background:
  Given user is logged in

Scenario: Create Valid Article   
  Given I have no articles                                
  And I am on the list of articles                       
  When I follow "New Article"                             
  And I fill in "article[title]" with "Spuds"        
  And I fill in "Content" with "Delicious potato wedges!" 
  And I press "Create"                                   
  Then I should see "New article created."                
  And I should see "Spuds"                                
  And I should see "Delicious potato wedges!"             
  And I should have 1 article            


common_steps.rb

def login user
  #stuff of login process
end

Given /^user is logged in$/ do
  @user = Factory.create(:user) #if you are using factory_girl
  login(@user)
end
```

Hope that helps!!!

Comment: Given user is logged in
Ambiguous match, found 2 elements matching field "user_email" (Capybara::Ambiguous)
     ./features/step_definitions/article_steps.rb:3:in `login'
     ./features/step_definitions/article_steps.rb:62:in `/^user is logged in$/'
      features/manage_articles.feature:7:in `Given user is logged in'

Comment: I have gone through with u r step but i am getting an error.Actually i am learning cucumber so it takes more time to understand the things.If you please suggest me good tutorial for cucumber testing that would help me.

Comment: It means that there something repeating. You can purchase a book for cucumber to learn like Fundamental of cucumber or gone through videos and documentation of cucumber is primary learning source.

Comment: Thanks, my test cases going green now actually their is conflict of form field id.

Answer (score 1):

As your authentication failed so your test scenario should be something like to authenticate user first...as without authentication it is not going to articles list page so The link "New Article" have not found and got that error

```
Scenario: Create Valid Article 
      When I am on the login page
      Then I filled up username as "abc"
      Then I filled up password as "abc"
      Then I follow "login" 
      Given I have no articles                                
      And I am on the list of articles                       
      When I follow "New Article"
```

or

```
 Scenario: Create Valid Article 
      Given User is authenticated        
      Given I have no articles                                
      And I am on the list of articles                       
      When I follow "New Article"
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, i will check and let you know the output.